# Disable all links in parent block but not in one of its child block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div having class say wrapper. Structure of html looks something like this.

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="header">
     <a href="http://mysite.com">LOGO</a>
   </div>
   <div class="nav">
     <!-- Anchors -->
   </div>
   <div class="container">
     <!-- Other contents anchors etc. -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way we can disable all the links inside wrapper except anchors in div having class "nav"? What could be the efficient way to do this?

I am using the following code to disable all links -

```
$('.wrapper').find('a').die('click');
$('.wrapper').find('a').unbind('click');
$('.wrapper').find('a').removeAttr('onclick');
$('.wrapper').find('a[href^="javascript"]').removeAttr('href');
```

Can we do it without making a check using loop? Or, it would affect the same , using loops and without using loops?

Comment: `$('.wrapper nav').bind('click');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.wrapper').find('a').not($('.wrapper').find('.nav a')).on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Base one the HarryFink's answer use something like this
(`closest` function is more more effective than `parents`)

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', 'a', function(e){  
    if(!$(this).closest('.nav')){  
        e.preventDefault();  
    }  
})
```

Comment: Yes, its true. And filtering to 'a' tag speeds up the script too.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', function(e){
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if(!$target.parents('.nav')){
         e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to target all `anchors`, which are descendants of `wrapper`, contained within another `div`, which doesn't have the class `nav`:

```
$('.wrapper div:not(".nav") a')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('.wrapper div:not(".nav") a').removeAttr('href');
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nf4t7/)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/jSEnu/1/

**CODE**

```
$(".wrapper div:not('.nav') a").prop("href", "#");
```

Answer (score 1):

Select them like this

```
$('div.wrapper > div:not(".nav") a')
```

A sample (not the same, just similar): http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/rGwtw/